# dijit toolbar on the left side instead on top

Tags: dojo, positioning, toolbar

so I didn't find something in the dijit Toolbar API I'll try it here.

Is it possible to place a dijit toolbar to another place than on top?

I'd like to create a Toolbar declarativly on the left side inside a contentpane so the toolbar is from top left, to bottom left.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you go with declarative approach for widget creation, you can write custom css for each of them .

So getting a custom layout doesnt seem to be a tough task. You can write some div container's with a fix width , break line after each menu item and get the required layout.

```
check this for example: 

    https://jsfiddle.net/GfB2B/2/
```

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. In my case I want the toolbar on the left side while there is a table with inputs on the right side. If I do it via css the whole height of the toolbar won't be usable?

Comment: can you share a screenshot or a jsfiddle would be the best.

Comment: [link how it should look like](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4044/qos3io9o_jpg) as you see there are tabcontainer, contentpanes and the toolbar where I'd like to place it

Comment: I think you can go with following hierarchy...Tabcontainer-->Border Container(left : Toolbar (Declarative,so you can align in HTML form), Right: Inner Tab Container)---> Content Panes(Inside right Inner Tab Container)